# Build object-introspection failed: yocto build

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I had errors when I built Yocto for the embedded device. I searched it on the Internet but nothing working. Please help me!

```
Caught exception: <type 'exceptions.IOError'> IOError(122, 'Disk quota exceeded')
    | > /data/phonghoang/build_yocto/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py(84)copyfile()
    | -> copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
```

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR: gobject-introspection-native-1.46.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: gobject-introspection-native-1.46.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /data/phonghoang/build_yocto/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gobject-introspection-native/1.46.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8291)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /data/phonghoang/build_yocto/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gobject-introspection-native/1.46.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8291
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

```
Caught exception: <type 'exceptions.IOError'> IOError(122, 'Disk quota exceeded')
```

seems to indicate that you're running out of disk. How much space do you have left on the partition where you're building?

Try to free up some space.

Comment: Thank you but I'm sure that It's enough free disk to build

Comment: Well, double check your disk and partition. Or do you have quotas enabled? Check that. What you're getting, is an exception from Python, indicating that you have exceeded your disk quota.